# Keyboard Brightness control not working on Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15ITL05. How to solve?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, lenovo, brightness

Running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15ITL05.

11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz × 8

Nvidia MX450

Graphics shows up as NVIDIA Corporation / Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)

X11/Xorg - Mutter

I have 2 buttons on my keyboard for brightness control -/+. These 2 are the only 2 buttons that do not function. The regular software slider DOES work.a

I have tried editing grub config to no avail.
Some guides told me to edit a xx-intel.conf file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d but this file does not exist for me.
I only have:

```
10-amdgpu.conf  10-quirks.conf  11-nvidia-offload.conf  70-wacom.conf
10-nvidia.conf  10-radeon.conf  40-libinput.conf
```

Anything else I could try doing?